# Where is the weekends game mode in the new client?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have been playing LoL with the old client because the new client gives me a lot of lag. A few moments ago I was on my desktop playing with the old client, the One-for-All game, available this weekend.

I wanted to try the new client hoping that Riot had fixed the lag spikes.

When I opened the playing tab I didn't find the One-for-All mode.

[image: Client Picture]

Where can I find this mode in the new client?

Comment: I don't know where it is but had to say it, **what an ugly client**. Hope we can stay with the old one for a a long time..

Comment: I actually enjoy this new client. Is more fluid. But everytime i play in it i got huge lag spikes. like i need to shutdown the computer after the game ends...

Comment: @Alex I remember everyone saying that about the in-game display when it changed too

Comment: @BenCraig I still say/think so, I liked it way more before than now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that [other players](http://eune.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/gameplay/rotating-game-mode-queue-now-live-25) are saying that the new client doesn't have the tab for the weekend game modes.  Instead, you have to restart the launcher, and press the legacy client button at the bottom right when logging in to use the old client to play this mode.

To quote the source:

> They haven't actually added any tab for the weekend modes... you need to restart lol, and when you're in the login screen just press launch legacy client at the right bottom corner and you will launch the old client and you can play weekend modes.

This will make you use the old client, where you can still play this mode.

Comment: But the next patch should include the RGMQ or "weekend modes". It's being tested on the current PBE patch